# What's the history of the mnemonic "Father Charles goes down and ends battle"

Tags: etymology, music, mnemonic

If you work your way around the 'circle of fifths' you work your way through all the major scales. For example, starting with C major if we add one sharp, F#, we get G major. Adding a second sharp, C#, gives us D major and a third, G#, A major. The way English speaking music students remember this is with the mnemonic:

> Father Charles goes down and ends battle

(N.B. Going the other way, adding flats, follows the mnemonic "Battle ends and down goes Charles' father".)

What is the history of this mnemonic?

Comment: I'm asking here in response to Doubt's question on the Music Practise and Performance Stack Exchange site: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/9858/2125

Comment: This one does have the advantage of being reversible. There are [lots of other versions](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Father-Charles-Goes-Down-and-Ends-Battle-%28mnemonic-for-Order-of-sharps-in-music%29-%28FCGDAEB%29.html) but as for finding the origin, I wish you luck!

Comment: Do any [other music mnemonics](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+Good+Boy+Does+Fine) have traceable origins? I'd be surprised; I would guess they simply catch on and evolve.

Comment: Good luck in finding out how, when, and where a particular mnemonic came into being.  The technique of using mnemonics goes back thousands of years.  The writer of Psalm 119, the longest song in the Bible, used successive letters of the Hebrew alphabet (22 altogether) to begin each section of the psalm, presumably to aid singers in memorizing it.  (Good luck!).  Early rhetoricians, too, used mnemonics to remember their talking points by assigning each to a different "haunt" or cubbyhole. I can't resist adding the Great Lakes mnemonic:  H-O-M-E-S.  Huron, Ontario, Michigan, Erie, Superior.

Comment: Since words have traceable histories (in print and beyond) why not mnemonic? I agree it sounds a difficult thing to research, but so are words, phrases, and many other aspects of English usage. No?

Comment: @Dumbledad: It may be hard to figure out _who_ first coined certain words or phrases, but one _can_ do some digging and figure out when such words first started appearing _in print_. Therefore, it may be possible to figure out when this was first printed in a music book, but it just seems like there's a good chance such cute memory devices were in use long before they found their way into print, because instructional authors would be more apt to borrow a common mneumonic than invent one of their own.

Comment: Thanks all. And whoever down-voted the question if you can explain why in a comment that'll help me phrase or choose questions better on here in the future.

Comment: Help with etymology is plainly on topic as long as the asker has done his research and included the results in the question. @dumbledad can you please do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1885, in an article about music education, the author wrote the *Father Charles* line, and attributed it to a "government schoolmistress," saying that it "emanated from one of the training colleges."

A similar mnemonic – Go Down And Enter By Force – is printed on the same page; that one is attributed to "some unknown author."

Reference: [Educational Plans in Music Teaching](http://books.google.com/books?id=KeoqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22Father%20Charles%20goes%20down%20and%20ends%20battle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_u4wUc_dNo220QHi-oHYDw&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22Father%20Charles%20goes%20down%20and%20ends%20battle%22&f=false), in *The Quarterly Music Review*, Vol. 1, 1885.

Comment: Wonderful evocative quote!